# Data estimation based on progression

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, standard-deviation, estimation

Given a data-set  $x$ and $y$.

```
    x   |    y 
------------------
153,000 | 0.058848
332,641 | 0.36352
506,629 | 0.53
```

If $x$ being the number of database records and $y$ the time taken in seconds to retrieve them, how do i estimate the time taken for 10,00,000 records considering the rate of time progression from the given data-set?

Comment: More data would be really helpful.

Comment: @Jacob Mayle: Can you mention a method by which such estimation can be calculated ?

Comment: Sure. I did a linear fit in excel and the least squares regression line through the origin is $y=0.000001046x$. Assuming this model, one would expect the retrieval time to be 1.046 seconds. This is a **very** rough and naive approximation that is probably inaccurate due to the dearth of data.